# Extract only pattern matched text

Tags: regex, perl

I have written a basic program using regular expression.
However the entire line is being returned instead of the matched part.

I want to extract the number only.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "ABMA 1234";
$line =~ /(\s)(\d){4}/;

print $line; #prints *ABMA 1234*
```

Is my regular expression incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the exact value with the corresponding values. And your are not removing the text `\w`;

```
use strict;  
use warnings;

my $line = "ABMA 1234";
$line=~s/([A-z]*)\s+(\d+)/$2/;

print $line; #prints only 1234
```

If you want to store the value in the new string then

```
(my $newstring = $line)=~s/([A-z]*)\s+(\d+)/$2/;

print $newstring; #prints only 1234
```

Just try this:

Comment: The character class `[A-z]` includes `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, and `\`` as well as the upper and lower case English letters. You want `[A-Za-z]`, or `[[:alpha:]]` or `\p{PosixAlpha}`, both of whixh need the `/a` modifier to prevent matching non-ASCII letters.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print 1234, you need to change your regex and print the 2nd match:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "ABMA 1234";
$line =~ /(\s)(\d{4})/;

print $2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you output the match in perl but you can use below regex for output the full match in your regex, you might getting space appended with your result in your current regex.

```
\b[\d]{4}
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/426AUg/1)

Comment: What is the use of character class in your regex?